# Na arquitetura MISD, os threads executados são independentes e manipulam dados diferentes?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software

Olá, a arquitetura de computação **MISD** tem como significado **Multiple Instruction, Single Data**. Ou seja, ela executa múltiplas instruções diferentes sobre o mesmo dado. No concurso para perito criminal federal ocorrido em 2014 porém, a afirmação a seguir foi dita como **correta**:

Por meio da técnica de pipeline, a arquitetura MIMD e a MISD podem executar múltiplos threads ao mesmo tempo. Na arquitetura MISD, os threads executados são independentes **e manipulam dados diferentes**.

Alguém consegue me explicar por que a afirmação foi dita como correta se ela se opõe a própria definição de MISD?

Comment: A afirmação está falsa. Os dados são os mesmos, então há uma concorrência pelo menos de leitura. Não creio que possa ser tratado de maneira totalmente independente como está escrito aí, mas o foco do erro está no grifo "**dados distintos**"

Answer (score -1):

As threads , principalmente na arquitetura MISD, são executadas sobre um mesmo processo, ou seja, não são independentes, e manipulam os mesmos dados.